# How to generate a labelled dendogram using agnes?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

Using the code from : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Hierarchical_Clustering

Here is how to generate a dendogram :

```
# import data
x <- read.table("data.txt")

# run AGNES
ag <- agnes (x, false, metric="euclidean", false, method ="single")

# print components of ag
print(ag)

# plot clusters
plot(ag, ask = FALSE, which.plots = NULL)
```

I'm receiving an error on

```
ag <- agnes (x, false, metric="euclidean", false, method ="single")
```

The error is :

```
Error in agnes(x, false, metric = "euclidean", false, method = "single") : 
  object 'false' not found
```

This implementation of agnes works but its generating numbered labels for the dendogram :

```
ag <- agnes (data, metric="euclidean")
# plot clusters
plot(ag, ask = FALSE, which.plots = NULL)
```

The dendogram :

[image]

The dendogram generated from `http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/Hierarchical_Clustering` includes labels :

[image]
Here is the data file :

```
,ba,fi,mi,vo,rm,to
ba,0,662,877,255,412,996
fi,662,0,295,468,268,400
mi,877,295,0,754,564,138
vo,255,468,754,0,219,869
rm,412,268,564,219,0,669
to,996,400,138,869,669,0
```

How can generate a labelled hierarchical cluster based on above data which is same as labelled dendogram above ?

Update :

After following @sgibb suggestion I used this :

```
ag <- agnes(data, FALSE, metric="euclidean", FALSE, method ="single")

# plot clusters
plot(ag, ask = FALSE, which.plots = NULL)
```

The dendogram being generated is now :

[image]

This is an incorrect structure. Maybe its beacuse the column names of my dataset are appearing as 1,2,3,4,5,6 and are not labelled, if so how can I modify the import statement ?

the dataset imported :

[image]

Comment: In R you have to use `FALSE` not `false`! I don't know `agnes` but try `agnes(x, FALSE, metric="euclidean", FALSE, method ="single")`.

Comment: @sgibb thanks, FALSE did cause it to not throw an error but the labelling is still not working. And the dendogram does'nt look correct. please see question update

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about creating a dendogram, but rather about how to properly import your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was an extra comma in the dataset.

`running help(read.table)` and taking note of this section helped me solve the issue :

```
If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than the number of columns, the first column in the input is used for the row names. Otherwise if row.names is missing, the rows are numbered.
```

This works :

1. import the data vai the r gui
   data to import :

   ba,fi,mi,vo,rm,to
   ba,0,662,877,255,412,996
   fi,662,0,295,468,268,400
   mi,877,295,0,754,564,138
   vo,255,468,754,0,219,869
   rm,412,268,564,219,0,669
   to,996,400,138,869,669,0
2. run the commands :

ag <- agnes(data, FALSE, metric="euclidean", FALSE, method ="single")

plot(ag, ask = FALSE, which.plots = NULL)

This generates this dendogram which looks correct :

[image]

Comment: I upvoted the Q and the A because of the link to the wikibooks example.